# Copy badly-named files from one deeply-nested dir, content-address rename them, to another flattened sub-directory, in a Bash one-liner?

Tags: bash, md5, uuid, xargs, gnu-parallel

How do I copy files distributed throughout a deeply-nested sub-directory, to another sub-directory which is not nested at all (i.e., is flat)?  To heighten the difficulty level, I have these constraints/wrinkles.

1. Though the source files have the same extension (*.xlsx), they have spaces in the filenames.
2. The source sub-directory and all its contents are read-only.
3. Because of potential name collisions, because of the lousy filenames, because I have a herd of these files and their original names are useless to me, I want to content-address them *somehow*.
4. The scripting environment is Bash.
5. Because of other constraints, it's important to do this in one line.
6. Extra points for simplicity, because the more esoteric it is the less likely my colleagues will grok this.

I've tried `cp`, `find`, `xargs`, `parallel`, `uuidgen`, `md5sum`, Bash `for` loops, and various combinations thereof with limited success.  The best I've been able to achieve is generating a *random* UUID for each file.  That's OK, I guess, but it's not exactly the "content-addressing" I'd like, because I'd like to de-dupe the files based on their *content*.

For reference, that looks like this, where `source` and `dest` are the source and destination sub-directories.

```
find source/* -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do cp "$f" 'dest'/"$(uuidgen)"; done' Renamer {} +
```

Though UUIDs are nice, I don't have my heart set on them and am open to other ideas, modulo the constraints above.

Thanks!

Comment: `it's important to do this in one line.` - in shell, everything is one line - you can always remove newlines and replace them by `;`. `find source/*` is equal to `find source` (not counting hidden files)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "content addressing"?

Comment: do you want to name your xlsx files based on its content? what part of the content?

Comment: @KamilCuk I said that to try to inoculate against attempts to answer the question with a Bash script file.

Comment: @umläute What I mean by "content addressing" is I would like the following things to occur:  If there are two files that are in different parts of the nested source hierarchy but which otherwise have the same name, but whose contents are different, then don't clobber each other.  OTOH, if any two files have the same content, regardless of their names, one should clobber the other.  I.e., remove duplicates.

Comment: @umläute examples of content-addressing would be "Name a file according to an md5 hash of its contents" or "Name a file according to a uuid generated from its contents."

Comment: @1010 yes, I want to rename my xlsx files (while copying them...that's important) based on their content?  What content?  All of their content...every last non-nul byte.

Comment: Git [for instance](https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/git-content-based-addressing-branches-and-tags/#:~:text=Git%20uses%20a%20technique%20that,reasons%3A%20repository%20size%20and%20performance.) does content-based addressing.

Comment: What about naming them like android does when downloading files? Like if you download a file the first time, it's `filename.txt`, but then on second time I get `filename_1.txt`, then `filename_2.txt` etc. Ie. is there a specific requirement for the naming scheme you have in mind? Because it looks too broad - you want to rename files, how exactly do you want to rename them?.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't care one iota what the names are, so long as two files that have exactly the same content byte-for-byte, have exactly the same name.

Comment: `as two files that have exactly the same content byte-for-byte, have exactly the same name` Two files have to have different names, how two files are going to have the same name? `Name a file according to an md5 hash of its contents` why not do just that? `cp "$f" "$(md5sum <"$f" | cut -d' ' -f1)"`?

Comment: @KamilCuk That's right.  Typically, if two files are written to a directory and they have the same name, the one will clobber the other.  I.e., it will overwrite the other.  That is exactly what I want.

Comment: If it helps, consider the problem to be one of de-duping files, based not on their names but on their content.

Comment: @KamilCuk well I don't know, let me try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `md5sum` to calculate the `md5sum` of the content of a file:

```sh
find * -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do cp "$f" 'dest'/$(md5sum "$f" | sed -e s/[[:space:]].*//); done' _ {} +
```

This uses `sed` to massage the output of `md5sum` to not contain the filename rather than the usual `md5sum <file> | awk' {print $1}'` so that I don't have to think about escaping quotes.

Of course, you might have hash collisions with md5, but you can easily switch the hashing to use `sha256sum` or whatever you like.

Comment: Because that solution gets tripped up by the spaces in the filenames:  https://asciinema.org/a/365830

Comment: I haven't looked at the video (please just explain what's wrong) but added quotes which might rectify the problem.

Comment: @tripleee what was wrong with the original solution was that it broke because of the spaces in the filenames.  But, with your edit, it works, so, you win the prize.

Comment: Now.  Does anyone want to try replacing `md5sum` with `uuidgen`?

Comment: Also, "why don't" I do that?  Because if I knew the answer, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: "... replacing md5sum with uuidgen". UUIDs are not about "content-addressing" but about generating unique IDs, so `uuidgen` doesn't allow a file input. why do you insist on using it if you want to be able to distinguish the file-contents based on the file-name?

Answer (score 1):

umläute's solution is a bit shorter if using GNU Parallel:

```
find * -type f -print0 | parallel -0 cp {} dest/'$(md5sum {} | sed -e s/[[:space:]].*//)'
```

Tested on file names containing multiple consecutive spaces and newlines.